# Spark: createDataset() into a Dataset<Row>?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Due to API reason, my test program needs to get a `Dataset<Row>` to set up a test, but I could not find any easier way to do it with `createDataset()` than this:

```
Dataset<String> datasetString =
    spark.createDataset(Arrays.asList(
        "Country",
        "UK", "US", "UK", "US", "UK",
        "US", "UK", "US", "UK", "US")
        , Encoders.STRING());
Dataset<Row> dfOneCol =
    spark
        .read()
        .format("csv")
        .option("header", "true")
        .csv(datasetString);
```

Is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<String> points = Arrays.asList("UK", "US", "Foo", "Bar");
dataset = spark.createDataset(points, Encoders. STRING()).toDF("Country");
```

Hope it helps